# Phase space formulation: "Representation" vs "function" vs "quasi-probability distribution"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, phase-space

In the phase space formulation, the terms "representation", "function, and "quasi-probability distribution" (as in [Glauber–Sudarshan P representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation), $P$-function) seem to be used interchangeably. 
I wonder about the semantics of these terms: Do they all really mean exactly the same thing, even mathematically, or might there be some subtleties to be understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three things all emphasize different properties:

- "Function": reminds you you're dealing with a function on phase space. Also the shortest one, so can be used for convenience.
- "Representation": reminds you this function represents the content of a particular quantum state.
- "Quasi-probability distribution": reminds you this function is like a probability distribution but isn't really one.

These adjectives end up being used interchangably not because they mean the same thing, but because the three most common things they're applied to ($P$-function, $Q$-function, Wigner function) have all three of these properties.

Comment: A small tweak: in that article, "representation" is mostly used to contradistinguish functions derived by different operator-ordering maps. They are equivalent, but different rules for producing different functions (P, Q, and W, and... and...) corresponding to ("representing") the same operators and physical quantities.